# How to configure jackson to not to serialize byte array?

Tags: java, serialization, arrays, jackson, binary-data

I have an JSON like object, which also has some binary values.
I do not want the binary(`byte[]`) data to be serialized.

I have tried to add custom serializer for `byte[]`. But it didn't worked out.

Try 1:

```
    public class ByteArraySerialiser extends SerializerBase<Byte[]> {

    protected ByteArraySerialiser() {
        super(Byte[].class, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Byte[] arg0, JsonGenerator arg1,
            SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException,
            JsonGenerationException {
        arg1.writeString("");
    }

}
```

Try 2:

```
    public class ByteArraySerialiser extends SerializerBase<Byte> {

    protected ByteArraySerialiser() {
        super(Byte.class, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Byte arg0, JsonGenerator arg1,
            SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException,
            JsonGenerationException {
        arg1.writeString("");
    }

}
```

But, both are failing to override the default serializer.

I could not use annotation because, its a `Map<Object, Object>`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the JsonIgnore annotation on the getter or the field itself?
You can also use MixIn in order to do that. Example (taken from [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) open source):

```
public abstract class JsonNGuidMixIn extends NGuid {

    /**
     * Tells Jackson that the constructor with the {@link String} argument is to be used to deserialize the entity,
     * using the "uuid" property as the argument.
     *
     * @param candidate
     */
    @JsonCreator
    public JsonNGuidMixIn(@JsonProperty("uuid") String candidate) {
        super(candidate);
    }

    /**
     * Ignore this method since Jackson will try to recursively dereference it and fail to serialize.
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public abstract Guid getValue();
}
```

And the usage is at JSonObjectSerializer (copying paste a part of it here)

```
@Override
    public String serialize(Serializable payload) throws SerializationExeption {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(NGuid.class, JsonNGuidMixIn.class);
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Guid.class, JsonNGuidMixIn.class);
        mapper.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
        return writeJsonAsString(payload, mapper);
    }
```